# Error in Function EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2008-r2

i use Entity Framework + SQl 2008 + .Net Framework 4 + SP in SQL.

and crate Function in EF for Insert value into sql.

fro EX:
Function Import Name: InsertStudent

stroed Procedure Name: InsertStudent

Returns a Collection Of: Scalars: Int32

SP:

```
create proc InsertStudent
(
@DateReg datetime,
@stdLastName nvarchar(50),
@stdFirstName nvarchar(50),
@Description nvarchar(500)
)
INSERT INTO Student(DateReg,stdLastName,stdFirstName,[Description])
VALUES (@DateReg,@stdLastName,@stdFirstName,@Description)
```

the Date Saving at SQL but Error in Function EF:

The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have enough columns for the query requested.

Comment: what's ur primary key in student table? r u insert value for that field in this statement?

Comment: What query? That's an INSERT statement. The only thing it's going to return is the number of rows affected.

Comment: @Til86: primary key in student table = stdID int

Comment: so u need to pass value for stdID. otherwise it takes null which is not allow to save. i think thats the problem.

Comment: I want to get the last value in stdID After Insert Value.

Comment: if the table has primary key, you need to insert record for primary key field. otherwise it not allow to save. you cant save get last value as primary key. @least it should be lastvalue+1

Comment: What should that "collection of scalars: int32" represent? How/why do you expect to get it from a single "insert"?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to insert primary key value for through sp.

```
create proc InsertStudent
 (
   @stdID int,
   @DateReg datetime,
   @stdLastName nvarchar(50),
   @stdFirstName nvarchar(50),
   @Description nvarchar(500)
)
INSERT INTO Student(stdID,DateReg,stdLastName,stdFirstName,[Description])
VALUES (@stdID,@DateReg,@stdLastName,@stdFirstName,@Description)
```

Comment: stdID has Identity and primary key.

Comment: stdID has Identity and primary key. no problam in insert value at sql.
I have similar needs SCOPE_IDENTITY(). for get the last value in stdID After Insert Value

Comment: without sp, plz try this in sql query window and check whether its possible or not. INSERT INTO Student(DateReg,stdLastName,stdFirstName,[Description])
VALUES ('07-12-2012','aa','bb','abc')

Comment: INSERT INTO Student(DateReg,stdLastName,stdFirstName,[Description]) VALUES ('07-12-2012','aa','bb','abc'). its OK.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1720381.aspx/1?The+data+reader+returned+by+the+store+data+provider+does+not+have+enough+columns+for+the+query+requested+ then check passing parameters data type